# No error, but the result is Undefined.javascript

Tags: javascript, input, undefined

no errors in code but output get undefined

**code**

```js
var xx = document.getElementById("stars").value;
var day;

switch (xx) {
  case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type='hidden' id="stars" value='4'>
```

I have tried many ways but didn't get any solution please help me  thanks in advance

Comment: it's string `4`

Comment: you have it to parse to int

Comment: Not a answer to you problem, just a tip. A better way to do the same is thing is to use an array like  `arr = ["Sunday", "Monday", ...]` and then use `arr[day]` to access the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` returns a string, and the values in your `case` expressions are numbers. One solution would be to use string literals there too:

```js
var xx = document.getElementById("stars").value;
var day;

switch (xx) {
  case '0':
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case '1':
    day = "Monday";
    break;
  case '2':
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
  case '3':
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
  case '4':
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
  case '5':
    day = "Friday";
    break;
  case '6':
    day = "Saturday";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type='hidden' id="stars" value='4'>
```

Comment: you mean `.value` returns a `string`.

Comment: Hi the reason is bcuz yow `xx` has a "4" and you're switch has a 4 and as we know 
"4" !== 4

Comment: @appleapple indeed, got caught up in the flow of writing. Thanks for noticing! Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

`Switch` statement uses [`strict equality comparison (===)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) to compare its expression against each `case` clause.

`.value` property returns a string. So value of `xx`, being a string, doesn't matches any `case` clause because value in each `case` clause is a number and strict equality comparison between values of two different types always evaluates to false. As a result, `day` is never initialized with a value other than its initial value of `undefined`

Changing the each `case` clause to a number will solve the problem

```
case "4":
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
```